# Get Object from Collection

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I'm building a grid out of rectangles.

I want to **click** one of the rectangles and its color should change.

However, I dont know how to access the rectangles in **Main** AFTER they've been created.

[image]

Main:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Shape;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application{

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        launch(args);
    }

    public void changeColor(Pane p) {
         p.setOnMouseClicked(me -> {
            double posX = me.getX();
            double posY = me.getY();

            int colX = (int)(posX / 30);
            int colY = (int) (posY / 30);

            ObservableList<Node> children = p.getChildren();
            for( Node d : children) {
                    if(d.getLayoutX() == colX && d.getLayoutY() == colY) {
                        // how can i access my rectangle here?
                        // basically, i want to be able to do .setFill()
                    }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Grid g = new Grid(30,30, 30);
        Pane window = g.render();
        Scene scene = new Scene(window, 500, 500);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        this.changeColor(window);

    }
}
```

Grid:

```
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;


public class Grid {

    Integer width, height, squareSize; 
    Color fill = Color.ALICEBLUE, 
        stroke = Color.BLACK;

    public Grid(int x, int y, int squareSize){
        this.width = x; 
        this.height = y;
        this.squareSize = squareSize;
    }

    public Pane render() {
        Pane p = new Pane();
        Rectangle [][] rect = new Rectangle[this.width][this.height];
        for(int i = 0; i < this.width; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < this.height; j++) {
                rect[i][j] = new Rectangle();
                rect[i][j].setX(i * width);
                rect[i][j].setY(j * height);
                rect[i][j].setWidth(this.squareSize);
                rect[i][j].setHeight(this.squareSize);
                rect[i][j].setFill(this.fill);
                rect[i][j].setStroke(this.stroke);              
                p.getChildren().add(rect[i][j]);
            }
        }
        return p;
    }
}
```

Can someone please help me to figure out how I can access my rectangles again in the main file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping with your current design, you simply need to test if the mouse clicked within a child and if that child is an instance of `Rectangle`; then you can cast and call `setFill`. However, I recommend changing the name of `changeColor` as that name does not represent what that method is doing.

```
public void installChangeColorHandler(Pane pane) {
    pane.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
        for (Node child : pane.getChildren()) {
            if (child instanceof Rectangle 
                    && child.contains(child.parentToLocal(event.getX(), event.getY()))) {
                ((Rectangle) child).setFill(/* YOUR COLOR */);
                event.consume();
                break;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Since the event handler is added to `Pane` the `x` and `y` mouse coordinates are relative to said `Pane`. But since your `Rectangle`s are direct children of `Pane` we can call `Node.parentToLocal` to transform those coordinates into the `Rectangle`'s space<sup>1</sup>. We then need to test if the bounds of the `Rectangle` contain those coordinates using `Node.contains`; if it does, change the fill.

That said, you may want to modify your code so that you're adding an/the `EventHandler` directly to the `Rectangle`s. That way you can use `Event.getSource()`. For instance<sup>2</sup>:

```
public Pane render(EventHandler<MouseEvent> onClick) {
    // outer loop...
        // inner loop...
            Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
            // configure r...
            r.setOnMouseClicked(onClick);
        // end inner loop...
    // end outer loop...
}

...

// may want to consume event
Pane window = new Grid(30, 30, 30).render(event ->
        ((Rectangle) event.getSource()).setFill(/* YOUR COLOR */));
```

---

<sup>1. Even if they weren't direct children you can still transform the coordinates into the local space. For example, you can use `Node.sceneToLocal` and the scene coordinates provided by the `MouseEvent` (i.e. `getSceneX()`/`getSceneY()`).</sup>
<sup>2. This is still staying close to your design. You may want to rethink things, however, into a proper MVC (or other) architecture. [Applying MVC With JavaFx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342864/applying-mvc-with-javafx?answertab=votes#tab-top)</sup>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191490/discussion-between-slaw-and-joel).